# WSO2 installing developer studio problems in helios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wso2

I'm trying to install WSO2 developer studios and carbon in my eclipse Helios for developing API2 software, the first issue is the page of wso2 site for download Eclipse Helios with Carbon studio is down, the download links doesn't work. So I have to manually install carbon studio.

I manage to do it so, now I'm having problems trying to install the developer studio, this is the error stack.

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Smooks Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Application Factory Tools 2.1.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appfactory.feature.feature.group 2.1.0)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.6.0.v20100505 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0.v20100505)
    Core Runtime 3.11.1.v20150903-1804 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.11.1.v20150903-1804)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110218-0812]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.2.20150902-0002)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0.v20100505]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AppFactory Tools UI 2.1.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.appfactory.ui 2.1.0)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Application Factory Tools 2.1.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appfactory.feature.feature.group 2.1.0)
    To: org.wso2.developerstudio.appfactory.ui [2.1.0]
```

Comment: The software you are trying to install requires a much newer version of Eclipse than the one you have installed.

Comment: What version of Eclipse Helios should I use then?

Comment: 'Helios' is the name of a specific release of the Eclipse IDE (version 3.6 to be exact) and is very old. The current release of the Eclipse IDE is 'Neon' (4.6). I don't know what the code you are trying to install requires, but the errors suggest it needs Eclipse 4.6 Neon or the previous 4.5 release (Mars).

Comment: If I use Eclipse Neon will install WSO2 without problems?

Comment: As I said I don't know about WSO2 I am just reading the error log you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Dev Studio download page](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) you can download latest `Eclipse JavaEE luna + Developer Studio v 3.8.0` zip.

Furthermore, for certain WSO2 products (eg. ESB, APIM), there is a separate tooling distribution which is customized dev studio. You can download them from `tooling` link in each product download page.